# socket on android, every second request disappears

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm writing simple software, PC is socket server, android connects to it and then whatever I write on keyboard on PC, android gets it and simply logs.

Android code:
    package com.example.socket;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.2.3", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("j", "Don't know about host: JANIPC.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("j", "Can't connect to Jani-PC");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        String userInput;


            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                //out.println(userInput);
                Log.e("j", "echo: " + in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }


}
```

And here goes my PC Java code:

```
package jani.study.socketserver;


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Jani
 */
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    String inputLine;

    System.out.println("Connected!");
    /*while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         out.println(inputLine);

    }*/
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.println("1");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.println("2");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.println("3");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.println("4");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.println("5");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.println("6");
    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}


}
```

In Android debugger, I only get every second request, I mean, I only get:
    echo: 2
    echo: 4
    echo: 6

what am I doing wrong? please help

Comment: solved, stupid mistake, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're using two `BufferedReader`s, one `in` and one `stdIn` both reading from the socket.  You are consuming the current line first in the `while` loop, then consuming the next in the `Log` statement.

Try this:

```
Log.e("j", "echo: " + userInput);
```

Comment: @JaniBaramidze  If you wish, you can mark the answer as correct so that future searchers may find it.

Answer (score 1):

You call `readLine` twice in the reader and only print the results of every other call to `readLine`. You probably want:

```
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            //out.println(userInput);
            Log.e("j", "echo: " + userInput);
        }
```